# Door makes loud bump upon closure

Tags: doors, door-frame

I have one interior door that is solid wood (84"x36"x1-3/4") in a metal stud wall with single layer of gypsum board on each side.  When I close the door, and the door slab hits the door stop it makes a hollow sounding bumping noise.  The other doors in our apartment which was renovated three years ago, do not make this noise.  When closing it, it sounds as though the door is bouncing off the door stop a few times.  To me it makes me wonder how well the assembly was framed, but I am hoping for suggestions on why the noise occurs, and what solutions there are to remedy it.

Comment: You might also want to try adjusting the strike plate - can the door jiggle when it's latched? If so, it's probably bouncing a little when you close it, adding to the noise problem. Try moving the strike plate so that when the door latches the door is snug against the frame.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to say what is causing the noise without an onsite inspection. Why not just try to muffle it (unless you are concerned about a structural problem).

Consider small bumpers, either [vinyl](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-Assorted-Self-Adhesive-Round-Vinyl-Bumpers-36-Pack-49969/203661151#), [cork](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-Cork-Cupboard-Door-Discs-24-Pieces-96954/202105615#) or [felt](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Richelieu-Hardware-Heavy-Duty-Felt-Disc-with-Adhesive-Back-1-In-Tan-75120XR/202205554?MERCH=REC-_-SearchPLPHorizontal1-3-_-NA-_-202205554-_-N#), something like these

[image: vinyl bumper]

[image: cork bumper]

[image: felt pad]

These are all self-stick and any of them could be put on the top and/or bottom edge of the strike side of the door frame. The can be cut to fit and may eliminate or at least reduce the banging.

Comment: Additionally, the door or the frame may be crooked, so the top or the bottom of the door contacts the frame when its closing. Say the top hits first, this may cause the bottom to 'slap' against the frame making a lot of noise. You can use those pads to try to eliminate this by adding extra pads in the right spots.

Answer (score 0):

Is the door frame metal or wood?

A pet peeve of mine is metal door frames that are supposed to be poured full of masonry (mortar, plaster/gypsum) post-install, and are not. The "hollow sound" leads me to ask.

It's a pet peeve because it turns out they are really easy to pry open without leaving marks, as the thieves who hit us when we lived behind one did. The masonry fill stiffens them up.

Otherwise, felt weatherstripping does wonders for muffling noisy doors.